# Replace placeholders which start with # then whole word

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I need to replace words that start with hash mark (#) inside a text.
Well I know how I can replace whole words.

`preg_replace("/\b".$variable."\b/", $value, $text);`

Because that \b modifier accepts only word characters so a word containing hash mark wont be replaced.

---

I have this html which contains #companyName type of variables which I replace with a value.

Comment: This question would be better with a [mcve].

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`\b` matches between an alphanumeric character (shorthand `\w`) and a non-alphanumeric character (`\W`), counting underscores as alphanumeric. This means, as you have seen, that it won't match before a `#` (unless that's preceded by an alnum character).

I suggest that you only surround your query word with `\b` if it starts and end with an alnum character.

So, perhaps something like this (although I don't know any PHP, so this may be syntactically completely wrong):

```
if (preg_match('/^\w/', $variable))
    $variable = '\b'.$variable;
if (preg_match('/\w$/', $variable))
    $variable = $variable.'\b';
preg_replace('/'.$variable.'/', $value, $text);
```

Comment: `\b` doensn't need to be between `\w` and `\W`. It will work fine [at the line start and end too](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html).

Comment: @alpha-mouse: Right, I forgot to mention that. The solution still stands, though.

Comment: +1 I came across your answer while preparing my own version of the the same question.

Comment: This option seems to work the best from this page; see http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/2c631af33d75aac6d3fe07af8768a3929572237c for running examples of the various suggestions

Answer (score 2):

All \b does is match a change between non-word and word characters. Since you know $variable starts with non-word characters, you just need to precede the match by a non-word character (\W).

However, since you are replacing, you *either* need to make the non-word match zero-width, i.e. a look-behind:

```
preg_replace("/(?<=\\W)".$variable."\\b/", $value, $text);
```

*or* incorporate the matched character into the replacement text:

```
preg_replace("/(\\W)".$variable."\\b/", $value, "$1$text");
```

Comment: The original question referred to "words that start with hash mark (#)", so that's what I answered.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just

```
preg_replace("/#\b".$variable."\b/", $value, $text);
```

Comment: i guess it should be `preg_replace("/\b#".$variable."\b/", $value, $text);`

Comment: @user338128: no, `#` is not considered as _word_ character, so it will not match.

Comment: Works fine with my example `up-to-date` - see @yasirfarooqui. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Following expression can also be used for marking boundaries for words containing non-word characters:-

```
 preg_replace("/(^|\s|\W)".$variable."($|\s|\W)/", $value, $text);
```

Comment: What is happening here? $variable should not be replaced when part of a hyphenated word. Instead, the last hyphen vanishes.


php > $text='up-to-date';
php > $variable='date';
php > $value='Date';
php > echo preg_replace("/(^|\s|\W)".$variable."($|\s|\W)/", $value, $text);
up-toDate